# tempdb data file is full. How to solve this issues

Tags: sql-server

**tempdb database data file is full**. How to solve this issues **without restart** the server.

Answer (score -1):

You do not. Someone obviously did bad things - too small db, too bad SQL that abuses tempdb. Now you live with the consequences.

Comment: Why? You can allow tempdb autogrow and ensure that disk has enough free space.

Comment: And ten you either have a small database or - sorry-  are not competent. Autogrow costs time. In any serious production database all files are preallcoated - especially tempdb. I only see autogrow in the following cases: Small no load databases and incompetent administrator.

Comment: Sure I'm not competent :) In emergency cases autogrow (or setting just bigger tempdb size limit) can help however. I would also think that competent admins do not ask nor answer such questions on stackoverflow anyway ;)

Comment: @Arvo Actually autogrow can not help in any sensible scenario because there will never be SPACE to grow into. TempDb (and logfiles) per best practices always live on separate and dedicated drives. As they are dedicated you can preallocate as much as sensible times 3-4 times... on a only slightly larger partition. SO no space to grow. EspeciallyTempDb really loves Raid 0 on SSD ;) So, id you ahve no dedicated setup for dempdb, you definitely fall into the "small and low throughput" dba.